# Cannot ping gateway (Intervlan routing)

Tags: networking, cisco, vlan

I have two switchs cisco 2960 (sw-120 and IDF1-SW) and router cisco 1841 (IDF1-R).

fa0/24 at sw-120 connected via fa0/7 at IDF1-SW

fa0/1 and fa0/24 at IDF1-SW switched to trunk mode

fa0/24 at sw-120 switched to trunk mode too

fa0/1 at sw-120 switched to access to vlan 120

Router(IDF1-R) configured to accept traffic from vlan 120 by subinterface fa0/1.120

```
IDF1-R(config-subif)#encapsulation dot1q 120
IDF1-R(config-subif)#ip ad 10.6.1.26 255.255.255.252
```

Laptop3 configuration is

```
IP : 10.6.1.25   
Subnetmask : 255.255.255.252
Gateway : 10.6.1.26
```

**Problem : I can not ping gateway(10.6.1.26) from laptop**

[image]

[image]

P.S. Sorry for my english its not my native language

Answer (score 1):

Would help to see full configuration of router and switches or atleast interface configuration of connected ports.

With that said it's unclear if port Fa0/7 on IDF1-SW is configured as a trunk port since you say that port 1 and 24 are trunks.

Verify that there is a trunk link that's up between the switches and between the switch and router and that vlan 120 is allowed on the trunks and exists on both switches. Can be verified with "show interfaces trunk" and "show vlan brief".